# Scroll two opened buffers in a split window at the same time

Tags: emacs

Sometimes I like to compare two opened buffers or scroll them at the same time with one click.
How to do that in emacs?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `scroll-all-mode`!

[Here](http://emacsblog.org/2007/03/08/quick-tip-scroll-all-mode/) you will find some further instructions/comments.

Comment: Mouse scroll or page down are buggy and might not work in this mode: [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScrollAllMode).

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Could you please provide a summary of its contents?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20200223192516/http://emacsblog.org/2007/03/08/quick-tip-scroll-all-mode/

Comment: From the archive linke by @Joe the key point is: "Try running M-x scroll-all-mode. Afterwards, scrolling commands entered in one window apply to all visibile windows."